# Can I use an Axiom 25 on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've just switched to Ubuntu and I like it so far. Now... I have an Axiom 25 keyboard. And I would like to use this on ubunte. I've googled but I can't really can't anything about it.

Is there anyone that got it working with Ubuntu?

Comment: Keyboards are pretty standard. Have you tried just plugging it in? If it doesn't work, how: is it not recognized at all? Do keys have the wrong effects? Are there nonstandard keys whose intended function is not performed? A link to a description of the keyboard would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you're talking about an MIDI Keyboard *(@Gilles not a typists' keyboard)*, you might want to look at this [howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/MIDI-HOWTO-7.html), which explains how to get Linux (not Ubuntu specifically) to recognize your hardware.